# How to show alert view once in view controller in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift

I am creating an app where when the user enters the page, an alert view pops up saying "Click on the button to proceed". How can I make the alert view show once in the view controller? Thanks for any help.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Info", message: "Click on the button to proceed", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    let myBackSign = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil)
    alertController.addAction(myBackSign )
    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: What do you by once? Is it in the entire app lifecycle?

Comment: @Lamar if I move the code to `viewWillAppear` will that show only once on the view controller?

Comment: @rmaddy - but questioner need only one time

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik But that doesn't change the fact that `viewDidLoad` is the wrong place to present another view controller.

Comment: @rmaddy - else alternate we need to create one bool value and need to check based on condition

Comment: @rmaddy do you know how to show the alert view once in the view controller?

Comment: @JustinS. Please see the duplicate question for the proper solution.